# JBoss 5 to jboss 7 migration guide

Tags: java, jboss, wildfly, jboss7.x, jboss5.x

How can i move from Jboss 5 to jboss 7. I can see huge difference in the file folder Structure and not sure which jboss 5 files wil be mapped to which jboss 7 files.plese provide any referance ? How much time its going to take

Comment: The main difference is that JBoss 7 has only one configuration file. How long it takes dependes on your application. Do you use datasources, messaging etc

Comment: I am connecting with external mainframe system which do have a lot of xml file,jks file certs and property file in jboss 5 . Where should I place these all files in respective Jboss7 folders ? Any guide?

Comment: https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_jboss_enterprise_application_platform/7.0/html/migration_guide/migrating_from_older_releases

Comment: @simon Thanks for it . Any suggestion on below ? .
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63402991/migration-from-jboss-to-jboss-eap-7-2-0-ga-gives-error-with-cics-jca-connectivit